# Using switch statements instead of using different functions in Backbone routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Backbone routing allows us to route to different pages.

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
  "help":                 "help",    // #help
  "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
  "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
 },

 help: function() {
  ...
 },
 search: function(query, page) {
  ...
 }

});
```

My question is instead of writing different functions for different routes, why not write a single function for all the routes and use a switch statement to determine the exact route and performing tasks based on the route.

It would look something like this.

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

 routes: {
"help":                 "main",    // #help
"search/:query":        "main",  // #search/kiwis
"search/:query/p:page": "main"   // #search/kiwis/p7
 },

 main: function() {
...
switch(){

 case("help") : ...;
 case("search") : ...; 
}
 }

});
```

I don't know the exact implementation. I just gave a brief idea. Is this possible in Backbone routing?

Comment: Why would you want to have one BIG function instead of having different functions fr different routes

Comment: Based on my requirements, I don't need different functions. One function is sufficient.

Comment: Then it makes no sense to create routes and use a single method

Comment: Any idea on what I should use?

Comment: You havent shared your use case yet

Comment: You're thinking about functions wrong. That "many functions" is actually behaving like a switch statement but with a different syntax. Don't get too hung up of the word `function`. Think of it as a kind of `case`.

Comment: If each case is just a one-liner and you don't have that many then go for it.

Comment: Its quite weird idea, but you can reach it easily - create default route - `*any` - it will match any route and hook up with your function

Comment: how do I get the exact route name from the routes? I tried it, but I don't know how to get the exact route name. If I get the route name then I can use it in the switch case

Answer (score 0):

Because that will lead to a nightmare hell as soon as you have more than 2 o 3 routes/functions, or you need anything more that 2 lines to setup the data and views for each route.

Also, it's much much easier to test your route handlers if you can simply call one function.

If you need one function per your requirements, then what's wrong is your route definition! I assume you are modeling a single page with search functionality and pagination of those search results. Let's suppose that page is accesed with a url like "yourapp/#page":

Enter optional parameters my friend: :)
http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "page(/search/:query)(/:page)": "main"
  },
  main: function(query, page) {
    if(query) {
      //you're searching
      if(page) {
         //display specific page
      }
      else {
         //show first results page
      }
    }
    else {
      //show you initial views/models
    }
  }
});
```

That route will handle: page, page/search/apples and page/search/apples/4

Comment: I tried to define the routes like this routes: {'','settings':'main'
    } when I try to run the application, I get an error telling "Unexpected token , "